# How to connect to JBoss EAP 7.3 using VisualVM in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, jboss7.x, visualvm

I am trying to connect an application with VisualVM, but VisualVM unable to connect with application: Below is the env:

- JBoss EAP 7.3
- Java 11
- OpenShift

I have tried to configure it in different ways, but all failed:

**Config try 1:**
Use few env variables in script file, so that it could execute first (file contents are mentioned below):
echo *** Adding system property for VisulVM ***

```
batch
/system-property=jboss.modules.system.pkgs:add(value="org.jboss.byteman,com.manageengine,org.jboss.logmanager")
/system-property=java.util.logging.manager:add(value="org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
run-batch
```

I can see that above commands executed successfully and above properties are available in JBoss config (I verified using Jboss cli command).

```
JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=3001 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.2.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.14.Final-redhat-00001.jar
```

**Result**:

```
- java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0079: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging
- Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYLOG0078: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
```

**Config 2:**

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=3001 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.2.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.14.Final-redhat-00001.jar
```

**Result:**

```
WARNING: Failed to instantiate LoggerFinder provider; Using default.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
```

**Config 3:**

•   Modify in standalone.conf, where I put all required configuration in this file.

**Result**:

```
WARNING: Failed to instantiate LoggerFinder provider; Using default.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
```

Kindly suggest that what is the correct configurations?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?